# WSDL Service placeholder explanation

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am a newbie learning web services. I'm trying to understand a WSDL and then develop a Java project. Inside the WSDL, the service part is as follows:

```
<wsdl:service name="MyService">
 <wsdl:port binding="tns:MyServicePortSoap11" name="MyServicePortSoap11">
     <soap:address location="https://localhost.myservice.local:400/wsg/ws"/>
 </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

But the endpoint which has been used in the demo of the web service is just `https://MyService:400/ws`. Why is the `/wsg/` missing from the address? Any documents or videos explaining this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<soap:address>` inside the WSDL is just a hint for your tooling. When you generate client code from a WSDL, the tool can use this address in the generated code to prefill the address of the web service for the calls you can make with the generated client code.

But it is just a hint.

[Your WSDL and SOAP service are not the same thing](https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b). Once you have generated the client code from the WSDL, you can use that code to call the web service no matter where it is deployed, on any kind of address, not just the one mentioned inside the WSDL.

Ideally, the `<soap:address>` inside the WSDL and the actual address of the web service should be the same so that it doesn't cause confusion, but they can be different. The actual address of the web service is important, not the one from the WSDL.